# How to fix "Issuer Certificate Is Invalid" error trying to Send to Firebase Cloud Messaging from PHP Curl on CENTOS 7?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not an SSL wizard, so I'm hoping that someone who is can help with this. I am developing an app demo that was able to send FCM messages successfully a while back. The mobile app calls a PHP script on the CentOS 7 server that uses the following code to send the request. This worked just fine.

```
                        $notification = array('title' =>$this->title , 'body' => $this->body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
//                      $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
                        $params_android = array('ttl'=>'0s','priority'=>'high');
                        $headers_apns = array('apns-expiration'=>'400','apns-priority'=>'10');
                        $params_apns = array('headers'=>$headers_apns);
                        // if only one recipient, must use the 'to' field instead of registration_ids
                        if (1 == sizeof($this->recipients)) {
                                $arrayToSend = array('to' => $this->recipients[0], 'notification' => $notification, 'android'=>$params_and$
                        } else {
                                $arrayToSend = array('registration_ids' => $this->recipients, 'notification' => $notification, 'android'=>$
                        }
                        $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);

                        $headers = array();
                        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
                        $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. self::$SERVER_KEY_COMMTEST;
                        $ch = curl_init();

                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$FCM_URL);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        //Send the request
                        $response = curl_exec($ch);

                        //Close request
                        if ($response === FALSE) {
                                $this->errorstring .= curl_error($ch) . "\n";
                                return false;
                        }
                        curl_close($ch);

                        $this->fcm_response = $response;
```

The URL to which I send the request is provided by Google: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

About six months ago, I paused work on this project. Now, I'm trying to resume it but the FCM calls return an error: "Issuer Certificate Is Invalid"

FCM support has been useless on this.

I can issue a manual CURL call from the command line to get a more detailed response. It is:

```
curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I see a link to more details in the detailed response. It suggests I need to obtain certificates and go through an installation process. Where do I get said certificates?

Is this a certificate error on my server or theirs? And, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved. For information's sake, here it is.

The DNS servers configured on my Linux server were not providing the DNS information it needed. Therefore, outgoing requests were being intercepted along the way by the ISP. Naturally, that meant calls supposedly going out to FCM were really hitting the ISP's server and there was an SSL certificate mismatch situation.

This was resolved by contacting the ISP that provided new DNS server addresses. Now, outgoing requests are reaching their correct destinations.